# include HTMLPURIFIER file cause error on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have an error on this code

```
if (Configuration::get('PS_USE_HTMLPURIFIER')) {

 require_once(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/tools/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php');
}
```

the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/luvsecret/public_html/www.jacketsshops.com/tools/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/luvsecret/public_html/www.jacketsshops.com/config/config.inc.php on line 135
```

The file permission is 644, the file exists and folder permission is 755
When commenting the code the website returns to work.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on path, you should replace _PS_ROOT_DIR_ with _PS_TOOL_DIR_

```
if (Configuration::get('PS_USE_HTMLPURIFIER')) {
    require_once(_PS_TOOL_DIR_.'htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php');
}
```